# C# - Inserting and Removing from Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

1. If I insert to Cache by assigning the value:

   Cache["key"] = value;

   what's the expiration time?
2. Removing the same value from Cache:

   I want to check if the value is in Cache by `if(Cache["key"]!=null)`, is it better to    remove it from Cache by `Cache.Remove("key")` or `Cache["key"]=null` ?

**-- Edit --**

After having tried `Cache.Remove` and `Cache["key"]=null`, DO NOT USE `Cache["key"]=null`, as it will throw exceptions when used in stress.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1 `Cache["key"] = value` is equal to `Cache.Insert("key", value)`

[MSDN Cache.Insert - method (String, Object):](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bawy15w.aspx)

> This method will overwrite an existing
>   cache item whose key matches the key
>   parameter. The object added to the
>   cache using this overload of the
>   Insert method is inserted with no file
>   or cache dependencies, a priority of
>   Default, a sliding expiration value of
>   NoSlidingExpiration, and an absolute
>   expiration value of
>   NoAbsoluteExpiration.

2 It's better to remove values from cache by Cache.Remove("key").
If you use `Cache["key"] = null` it's equal to `Cache.Insert("key", null)`.
Take a look at the `Cache.Insert` implementation:

```
public void Insert(string key, object value)
{
    this._cacheInternal.DoInsert(true, key, value, null, NoAbsoluteExpiration, NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null, true);
}
```

and `CacheInternal.DoInsert`:

```
internal object DoInsert(bool isPublic, string key, object value, CacheDependency dependencies, DateTime utcAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan slidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority priority, CacheItemRemovedCallback onRemoveCallback, bool replace)
{
    using (dependencies)
    {
        object obj2;
        CacheEntry cacheKey = new CacheEntry(key, value, dependencies, onRemoveCallback, utcAbsoluteExpiration, slidingExpiration, priority, isPublic);
        cacheKey = this.UpdateCache(cacheKey, cacheKey, replace, CacheItemRemovedReason.Removed, out obj2);
        if (cacheKey != null)
        {
            return cacheKey.Value;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Compare it to `Cache.Remove`:

```
public object Remove(string key)
{
    CacheKey cacheKey = new CacheKey(key, true);
    return this._cacheInternal.DoRemove(cacheKey, CacheItemRemovedReason.Removed);
}
```

`CacheInternal.DoRemove`:

```
internal object DoRemove(CacheKey cacheKey, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
{
    object obj2;
    this.UpdateCache(cacheKey, null, true, reason, out obj2);
    return obj2;
}
```

And finally `Cache.Remove("key")` is much more readble than `Cache["key"] = null`

Comment: in addition, it appears that removing from cache using Cache["key"]=null will cause your application to crash under stress. So I'd recommend Remove().

Comment: Cache["key"]=null will throw an ArgumentNullException - this is nothing to do with "stress".

Answer (score 3):

1. Add it to cache using [The add an item to the cache with expiration policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61(v=VS.85).aspx)  to specify exact time frame.
   As for the default, see in [ASP.NET Caching: Techniques and Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx) - the section titled **Storing Data in the Cache** specifies:

   > Cache["key"] = "value";
   >
   > This will store the item in the cache
   >   without any dependencies, so it will
   >   not expire unless the cache engine
   >   removes it in order to make room for
   >   additional cached data.
2. As the cache takes an object - Null is an object! if you want an entry with value of null, use `Cache["key"]=null` if you want no entry by the name "key" use `Cache.Remove("key")`

Comment: Important note: Using Cache[key]=null will throw an exception when used under stress, even though it works fine under normal conditions. Cache.Remove() doesn't explode under stress.

Answer (score 2):

1. When no expiration time is specified `NoSlidingExpiration` and `NoAbsoluteExpiration` is set where [NoAbsoluteExpiration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.noabsoluteexpiration.aspx) is the largest possible DateTimeValue. Hence it stays there forever till it is removed
2. Better remove the cache

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe that by default there is no default cache expiry time so I believe it stays in there until the app pool recycles.
2. This is the only way I know of to check if an item exists in cache

Comment: 1. Thanks. 2. OK, but what about the removal itself? What's the best practice in that case - Assigning null or Remove() ?